# AutoScroll to a offset in interactive viewer in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

With the `Interactive viewer` documentation i came to know that we can autoscroll to a particular position in `Interactive viewer` with `toScene` method.But i tried but everything in vain.How to autoscroll to an offset given the positions in interactive viewer

```
 import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

class MyPlanet extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyPlanetState createState() => _MyPlanetState();
}

class _MyPlanetState extends State<MyPlanet> {
  final TransformationController transformationController =
      TransformationController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
        setState(() {
          transformationController.value = Matrix4.identity()
            ..translate(800, 0.0);
          transformationController.toScene(Offset(800, 0.0));
        });
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InteractiveViewer(
      minScale: 0.5,
      maxScale: 1,
      constrained: false,
      transformationController: transformationController,
      child: Container(
        height: 896,
        width: 2000,
        child: Image.asset(
          'assets/images/rain_forest.png',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          height: double.infinity,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: *"But i tried but everything in vain."* - post your code then

Comment: @pskink Thanks, I have posted the code, please verify the code

Comment: you need something like: `transformationController.value = Matrix4.identity()..translate(x, y)`

Comment: what should be the translatedMatrix.Sorry i am new to flutter

Comment: check `Matrix4` officia documentation (for example if you want to scale it as well)

Comment: i dont want to scale.i just want to scroll to that position.Matrix4 does not seem to have that.It has zoom, scale, rotate

Comment: so if you want just to move to (x, )y position you have the code above

Comment: i tried but it is not working can you check the above updated code

Comment: pskink i have tried the same code.but it seems to be not working.When it ran it was only half the size of the screen and when i started scrolling it got full height(same as screen height)

Comment: Thanks it is working

Comment: @pskink can you post the working code that you showed me in pastebin it seems to be the link is not loading now

Comment: sorry, i dont have that code any longer

Comment: @pskink is there a way to animate the .translate?

Comment: @vontdeux `Matrix4Tween`?

Comment: i'm still fairly new with animation and flutter itself, but i have posted a question here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69327332/flutter-how-to-animate-matrix4-translate-when-button-is-tapped
just now, hope you can help explaining on how to add animation to the scrolling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks @pskink.
Autoscroll in interactive viewer can be achieved by using `TransformationController` and `matrix4`

```dart
@override
void initState() {
TransformationController transformationController =
      TransformationController();
transformationController.value = Matrix4.identity()
        ..translate(-200.0, 0.0); // translate(x,y);
}
```

Comment: Can you help me with this. I am using same but when after some translate i.e say (-700,0.0) I try to go to X axis at zero. So when I call transformationController.value.traslate(0.0,-500) then translate to (0.0,-500) is not performed but (-700,-500) is performed.

Answer (score 1):

Above solution not work for me - it move whole image on the screen, not only set needed position. I resolve issue with this example https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer/transformationController.html

Define end point for scroll for example by link:

```
Matrix4 scrollEnd = Matrix4.identity();
scrollEnd.setEntry(1, 3, -700); // y = 700

_controllerReset.reset();
_animationReset = Matrix4Tween(
  begin: Matrix4.identity(),
  end: scrollEnd,
).animate(_controllerReset);
  _animationReset!.addListener(_onAnimateReset);
  _controllerReset.forward();
```